# Deployment of web app fails during building using netlify

Tags: node.js, deployment, netlify, parceljs, build-error

I’m trying to deploy a web app using parcel but it fails during buiilding process.
Here is the complete log of the process:
Initializing:
2:21:21 AM: build-image version: 1ae4e4d7d5e3544ab1eb7f270391cdbb47c1e1e5 (focal)

2:21:21 AM: buildbot version: 1ae4e4d7d5e3544ab1eb7f270391cdbb47c1e1e5

2:21:21 AM: Fetching cached dependencies

2:21:21 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build

2:21:21 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build

2:21:21 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo

2:21:21 AM: git clone --filter=blob:none GitHub - ali-ab-2003/Moshify-2-

2:21:22 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main

2:21:23 AM: Starting to install dependencies

2:21:23 AM: Python version set to 3.8

2:21:24 AM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment

2:21:24 AM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2

2:21:25 AM: Started restoring cached go cache

2:21:25 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache

2:21:25 AM: go version go1.19.10 linux/amd64

2:21:25 AM: Using PHP version 8.0

2:21:26 AM: v18.16.1 is already installed.

2:21:26 AM: Now using node v18.16.1 (npm v9.5.1)

2:21:26 AM: Enabling Node.js Corepack

2:21:27 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins

2:21:27 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins

2:21:27 AM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies

2:21:27 AM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies

2:21:27 AM: No npm workspaces detected

2:21:27 AM: Started restoring cached node modules

2:21:27 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules

2:21:27 AM: Installing npm packages using npm version 9.5.1

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0:

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform’s native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1:

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN:

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3:

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package

2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1
2:21:29 AM: npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.

2:21:30 AM: npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated

2:21:30 AM: npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

2:21:31 AM: npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies

2:21:31 AM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

2:21:32 AM: npm WARN deprecated parcel-bundler@1.12.5: Parcel v1 is no longer maintained. Please migrate to v2, which is published under the ‘parcel’ package

2:21:32 AM: npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

2:21:34 AM: added 813 packages, and audited 814 packages in 6s

2:21:34 AM: 75 packages are looking for funding

2:21:34 AM: run npm fund for details

2:21:34 AM: 30 vulnerabilities (16 moderate, 14 high)

2:21:34 AM: To address all issues, run:

2:21:34 AM: npm audit fix

2:21:34 AM: Run npm audit for details.

2:21:34 AM: npm packages installed

2:21:34 AM: Install dependencies script success

2:21:34 AM: Starting build script

2:21:35 AM: Detected 1 framework(s)

2:21:35 AM: parcel at version 1.12.5

2:21:35 AM: Section completed: initializing
Building:
2:21:38 AM: Failed during stage ‘building site’: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:21:36 AM: Netlify Build
2:21:36 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: ❯ Version
2:21:36 AM: @netlify/build 29.15.3
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: ❯ Flags
2:21:36 AM: baseRelDir: true
2:21:36 AM: buildId: 64a881cf51fcd5144a4f2ef7
2:21:36 AM: deployId: 64a881cf51fcd5144a4f2ef9
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: ❯ Current directory
2:21:36 AM: /opt/build/repo
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: ❯ Config file
2:21:36 AM: No config file was defined: using default values.
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: ❯ Context
2:21:36 AM: production
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: Build command from Netlify app
2:21:36 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:21:36 AM: ​
2:21:36 AM: $ npm parcel build index.html
2:21:37 AM: Unknown command: parcel
2:21:37 AM: To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
2:21:37 AM: npm help
2:21:37 AM: ​
2:21:37 AM: build.command failed
2:21:37 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:21:37 AM: ​
2:21:37 AM: Error message
2:21:37 AM: Command failed with exit code 1: npm parcel build index.html (Search results for '"non-zero exit code: 1"' - Netlify Support Forums)
2:21:37 AM: ​
2:21:37 AM: Error location
2:21:37 AM: In Build command from Netlify app:
2:21:37 AM: npm parcel build index.html
2:21:37 AM: ​
2:21:37 AM: Resolved config
2:21:37 AM: build:
2:21:37 AM: command: npm parcel build index.html
2:21:37 AM: commandOrigin: ui
2:21:37 AM: environment:
2:21:37 AM: - CI
2:21:37 AM: publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
2:21:37 AM: publishOrigin: ui
2:21:38 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:21:38 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:21:39 AM: Finished processing build request in 17.527s

I tried to deploy a web app on netlify using parcel and expected it to work smoothly as I followed the tutotial to learn it as I should have.

Here is the screen shot of build settings as well:

[image: Build settings]